# Hyperledger Fabric Java SDK Error while instantiate java chaincode

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

Error: could not assemble transaction, err proposal response was not successful, error code 500, msg timeout expired while starting chaincode

Error while instantiating java chaincode

Command :

> peer chaincode instantiate -o orderer.example.com:7050 --tls --cafile
>   /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.example.com-cert.pem
>   -C mychannel -n test -l java -v 1.0 -c '{"Args":["init","a", "100", "b","200"]}' -P "AND ('Org1MSP.peer','Org2MSP.peer')"

Initially it was working fine but once the line of code increase instantiation gets slow down and now it is giving this error while instantiation

Comment: add the complete command not just the logs

Comment: Command : 
peer chaincode instantiate -o orderer.example.com:7050 --tls --cafile /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.example.com-cert.pem -C mychannel -n test -l java -v 1.0 -c '{"Args":["init","a", "100", "b","200"]}' -P "AND ('Org1MSP.peer','Org2MSP.peer')"

While instantiating java chaincode I am getting this error, Initially it is working fine  
but once the line of code increases it is giving this error.

Answer (score 0):

unfortunatelly, java chaincode always shows the same error. I had the same issue, please, check that you have the main function in the code. If you can share the code here, that would be awesome.

Comment: Yes it has main function & it is the same chaincode which gets clone in fabric-samples version : 4  chaincode_example02/java

Answer (score 0):

There can be multiple reasons for this, like if you are in a proxy, include your settings in a gradle.properties file. another can be, check your chaincode for errors if it was working fine then it should now, increase in no. of line doesn't affect instantiation. If you are not in a proxy and still facing the error try to include your chaincode in the question.